# Question for a sentence in Adelphoe

Tags: sentence-translation, grammar-identification, terence

In Terence's *Adelphoe* [3.4](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0086%3Aact%3D3%3Ascene%3D4), there is:

> fient quae fieri aequum est omnia.

***omnia***, ***quae***, ***fient*** are all plural, why is ***aequum est*** singular, what is the role of ***quae*** in its clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Aequum est* means “it is right, proper” and usually takes an AcI to say *what* is right and proper. For example, *aequum est vos ignoscere* means: “It is proper that you should forgive.” Passive infinitives are, of course, also welcome.

In this case, the AcI is *quae fieri*, “which to be done.” This is part of the relative clause *quae fieri aequum est*, “which is proper to be done.” Thus the meaning of the whole sentence is:

> All that is proper to be done, will be done.

(The neutral plural, as often, is used to talk about generic “things” without specifying them further.)